# I am getting following error : not a valid attribute definition in sequelize

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

How would I get COUNT and following columns group by email order by desc using sequelize. I am getting following error : not a valid attribute definition.

const data = await NominationModel.findAll({attributes: ['email', 'nomineename',[sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('email'))]] });

I am trying to get below sql query using sequelize.

`SELECT COUNT(1),nomineename, email FROM devchoice.nominations GROUP BY (email) order by email desc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to miss the `group` in sequelize, try this:

```
NominationModel.findAll({
    group: ['email', 'nomineename'],
    attributes: ['email', 'nomineename', [sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('email')), 'count']],
    order: [
        [Sequelize.literal('count'), 'DESC']
    ],
    raw: true
}).then((rst) => {
    console.log('rst' ,rst);
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log('err', err);
})
```